# How can I programatically check if the user has allowed my app to, "Store files on this device," in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, file, google-chrome, local-storage

When my app opens in Google Chrome, Chrome prompts the user to grant the app permission to store files ([screenshot](http://imageshack.com/a/img922/6679/E2PNLe.jpg)).  How can I programmatically (with JavaScript) check if the user has granted such access?

The motivation for my question is that currently, if the user does not allow access, and continues to try and use the app, it fails without any descriptive notice to the user.  In fact, the app simply displays the app's loading screen indefinitely.  So in my code I was hoping to make a check that the user has granted access to this storage--if not, then I'll ensure a helpful message is displayed to the user.

I had a look through previous Stack Overflow questions, but did not find this particular question.

Also, what storage is this Chrome prompt referencing?  Temporary and persistent storage (as described [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/offline_storage/#types))?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can check which permission are set for Chrome by checking `chrome.permissions`.

```
chrome.permissions.contains({
  permissions: ['tabs'],
  origins: ['http://www.google.com/']
}, function(result) {
  if (result) {
    // The extension has the permissions.
  } else {
    // The extension doesn't have the permissions.
  }
});
```

There is an expermimental Web API for this as well which you can use, as it is supported in Chrome.

```
navigator.permissions.query(PermissionDescriptor).then(function(permissionStatus) { ... })
```

Sources:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions/query#syntax
- https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/permissions/#step-4-check-the-extensions-current-permissions

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply, and welcome to Stack Overflow :-)  I tried to use `chrome.permissions`, but that method isn't available to my script.  An object named `chrome` is available in the global scope, but it does not possess a method named `permissions` (screenshot: http://imageshack.com/a/img924/2962/JNRzHh.jpg).  Am I missing a step?

Comment: Sorry, the use of 'method is incorrect in my previous comment.  That should be 'object.'

Comment: In step 3 they mention the following:
" // Permissions must be requested from inside a user gesture, like a button's click handler.". navigator.permissions does work for me in the console though, so I would suggest using thay one.

Comment: OK I tried `navigator.permissions` instead of `chrome.permissions`.  That is defined.  But I can't figure out how to check the permission in-question. I was under the impression the prompt I'm seeing is to allow access to persistent storage.  But when I run the `query()` method and pass it the value of `persistent-storage`, it returns a state of `prompt`, regardless of whether the user has granted access or not.

Comment: Here is a screenshot showing a value of `prompt` before the user has graned access (http://imageshack.com/a/img924/1083/TOAF8m.jpg).  Here is a screenshot showing a value of `prompt` after the user has graned access (http://imageshack.com/a/img923/2857/yfbmtu.jpg).  Shouldn't that `prompt` change to `granted`?